# AttributeSet value returns @2131296269 - what is it and how to use?

Tags: android, xml

If I define some view in xml like:

```
        <com.android.view.AlphabetButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:texSize="@dimen/alphabet_button_text_size"/>
```

and then at init with AttributeSet:

```
public AlphabetButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if (attrs!=null){

        String textSizeAttribute = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "textSize");
```

this `textSizeAttribute` value is like:

> 05-01 16:00:21.154: I/AlphabetButton(8738): textSizeAttribute
>   @2131296269

which I assume is something like a link via R to needed attribute. The question is how to evaluate it? I tried:

```
if (textSizeAttribute.substring(0, 1).equals("@"))
                Log.i(this, "textSize is "+context.getResources().getDimension(Integer.valueOf(textSizeAttribute.substring(1))));
```

but this returns wrong value. If I define it like `android:texSize="20sp"` instead of @dimen-link    then `textSizeAttribute` returns `20.0sp` which is correct.

**UPDATE**
I made an research and found that 2131296269 (0x7f09000d) links to correct value in my R.java:

```
    public static final class dimen {
        public static final int alphabet_button_width=0x7f09000b;
        public static final int alphabet_button_height=0x7f09000c;
        public static final int alphabet_button_text_size=0x7f09000d;
...
```

and dimens.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <dimen name="alphabet_button_width">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="alphabet_button_height">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="alphabet_button_text_size">20sp</dimen>
    ...
```

but it returns 30 instead of defined 20 can't figure why... Here is the log output:

```
05-01 16:18:14.284: I/AlphabetButton(9418): textSizeAttribute @2131296269 
05-01 16:18:14.284: I/AlphabetButton(9418): R.id is 2131296269 
05-01 16:18:14.284: I/AlphabetButton(9418): textSize is 30.0
```

and corresponding code lines:

```
public AlphabetButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if (attrs!=null){

        String textSizeAttribute = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "textSize");
        Log.i(this, "textSizeAttribute "+textSizeAttribute);
        Log.i(this, "R.id is "+textSizeAttribute.substring(1));
        Log.i(this, "textSize is "+context.getResources().getDimension(Integer.valueOf(textSizeAttribute.substring(1))));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dealing with this issue as well, and most likely android is scaling the original value of 20 up to 30 according the the screens density, which in your case is most likely 240 DPI, which would yield a scaling factor of 1.5

http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/android-tablet-usage-tips-tricks/9444-lcd-density-explained.html
   http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You can confirm these values by printing the following display metrics 
(in Mono/C#, needs minor translation for raw Android/Java):

this.ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
   this.ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.DensityDpi;
   this.ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Xdpi;
   this.ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Ydpi;
   this.ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
   this.ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;

Comment: And the only workaround is to get String from dimens instead of just dimens as itself. This issue relies only to textSize like if a value you trying to get is measured with sp AOS will return scaled value unlike with dp measured values.

Comment: It does seem only with text size (well, for me as well). However, I tried using both "sp" and "dip" metrics for font size with the same scaling issue, as well as reading in the attribute in almost everyway possible (strings, reference id's, direct attributes, styled attributes, dimens, no dimesn ...). Here is a link to my specific problem if your interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679526/android-scaling-density-issues

Comment: ... Oh, wait, I think I got ya about the string read... That way, your getting the value as declared, without a chance for android to scale it, then you just need to parse the string into an integer (or whatever). Is that what you mean ?